# kafka : Reading from second topic based on offset recvd from first

Tags: apache-kafka

From what I understand, Kafka client maintains its own offset. So is it possible, that I recv a message from topic it contains offset of message of some other topic.
Then I can go to that topic and read from it.

Logic is something

```
Loop
{
Get Message from first topic, get target topic and offset
read from target topic message with offset
process target message
sleep
} Do(true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is possible, it's a **very discouraged pattern**.

Most of the kafka performance rely on the serial reading (contrary to the random io), so from the performance POV and design goals it's perfectly fine to do such rewinds if you had, say, outage and you want to replay a series of messages. Having said this, working with kafka through the constant seeks and one-at-a-time processing is a very dreaded way.

Comment: Hello,Our issue is , the number of paritions is very less comparend to distinct value of ParitionKey. One client can just listen to One distinct value (others have to be discarded), For example : I have 4 clients . I have a topic in which message are coming like ("A",Msg1),("B",Msg2), ("C",Msg3) and so on. One client is only interested in "A" , if i try to do filtering at client side, deserializing huge message becomes a issue, If I try to break the message into small parts , sequencing becomes a issue (multiple producers are writing to single parition). Any suggestions

Comment: @user2799564 1a) can you partially deserialize message? 1b) Even if you can't (e.g. there is some complicated scheme of serialization or some non-trivial compression), messages keys are persisted all the way down from producer to the consumer, you can use message key to perform filtering 2) Are keys set is finite and quite low? If so you can split different kinds of messages across different topics and consume from only the ones that your client need to.

Comment: 1 question, can the Kafka client request the Kafka to just return the keys, instead of complete message ? Our messages are atleast 2 MB in size (withzip) , so if we can just get the skip, and based on that we can skip and go to next message (we will be having 1000 clients) is it viable solution. We have like 2000 different kinds of messages, having 2000, is it ok to have so many topics with multiple paritions

Comment: @user2799564 2. as far as I know, no, [fetch-only-key functionality is not supported by the protocol](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-Messagesets) 2. Well, I would say 2000 is likely too much, even through it's more like a wild guess -- I don't have raw data and tests behind this statement